# Out Of Memory when using Samsung SPen SDK examples

Tags: android, android-emulator

I wanted to develop an app using Samsung SPen SDK. There's an examples in the resources that given by Samsung, but when i tried to run it on AVD it comes to error. It said Out Of Memory.

I've check http://galaxynotespenchallenge.com/forum_topics/657 but there's no solution for this.

Is there anybody out there has the same problem as mine and solved it?

Here's my AVD config:

Target: Android 2.3.3 - API Level 10, 
Max VM Application Heap Size: 256, 
Device ram size: 512

and here is the error:

```
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335): java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: bitmap size exceeds VM budget
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.nativeDecodeStream(Native Method)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.graphics.BitmapFactory.decodeStream(BitmapFactory.java:470)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.cl.a(SourceFile:56)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.ao.h(SourceFile:198)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.ao.g(SourceFile:172)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.ao.c(SourceFile:105)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.ao.a(SourceFile:93)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.AbstractSettingView.j(SourceFile:2806)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.AbstractSettingView.a(SourceFile:561)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.AbstractSettingView.<init>(SourceFile:429)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.SettingView.<init>(SourceFile:137)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.spen.a.d.b.onCreateSettingView(SourceFile:591)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.spen.a.g.b.a(SourceFile:74)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.spensdk.SCanvasView.b(SourceFile:382)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.spensdk.SCanvasView.c(SourceFile:362)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.spensdk.SCanvasView.a(SourceFile:359)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.spensdk.SCanvasView$12.onFinish(SourceFile:4543)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.samsung.sdraw.CanvasView.onLayout(SourceFile:597)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.RelativeLayout.onLayout(RelativeLayout.java:912)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.setChildFrame(LinearLayout.java:1254)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.layoutVertical(LinearLayout.java:1130)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.LinearLayout.onLayout(LinearLayout.java:1047)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.widget.FrameLayout.onLayout(FrameLayout.java:338)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.View.layout(View.java:7175)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.ViewRoot.performTraversals(ViewRoot.java:1140)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.view.ViewRoot.handleMessage(ViewRoot.java:1859)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:123)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:3683)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:839)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:597)
09-03 11:10:28.712: E/AndroidRuntime(335):  at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

thanks in advance

Comment: you should post code and error, then someone will help

Answer (score 0):

Have you carefully read the last comment of the link you have posted.

> We are working on the problem with the emulator. In the interim, SDK
>   1.5 is still available. Version 1.5 does work with the emulator. It will give a good feel for what it's like to work with the SDK in
>   general. You can find it at
>   http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=10210
>
> Hod

It seems that only Version 1.5 is working and they are trying to fix the problem, well to my understanding.

Comment: but, i am using the latest SPen SDK. the version is 2.2 and they said it has some new features and fix some bug in the previous version [link]http://innovator.samsungmobile.com/cms/cnts/knowledge.detail.view.do?platformId=1&cntsId=11924&nacode=uk

i think the AVD configuration is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Please check additional properties of AVD.
The option you need is "Max VM application size". Set it to 100Mb and check will the problem be solved or not.

Good luck